# Multiprocessing slower than sequential Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use some multi-processing with python to increase the speed of some function, I know creating a process have a big cost but my function is taking something arount 3 sec to execute in sequential so I was thinking that some multi-processing could do the trick.

I was wrong (big whoop) the multi-processing seems slower or at least is not faster.
To put some context here what I had before the multi-processing:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        result = my_function(my_args)
```

And now what I have with the multi-processing:

```
pool = Pool()

for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        result = pool.apply_async(my_function,my_args).get()

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I replace the real function with the my_function thingy because my function is a pain in the ass to read basically.

So is the workload to small to use multiprocessing or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

As some said it was working sequential because I used the get each time where I needed to use it at the end after the join but now I have a random exception that pop from time to time, here the end of the traceback:

File "/home/rtodo/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
IndexError: pop index out of range

here's my code corrected

```
pool = Pool()
for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        neigbhourhood[i][j] = pool.apply_async(my_function,my_args)



for k in range(0, 3):
    for l in range(0, 3):
            neigbhourhood[i][j] = neigbhourhood[i][j].get()

pool.close()
```

Where neigbhourhood is a 3x3 array.

Edit of the Edit:
I changed a bit the code, now the pool close after the get and I don't use join.

Comment: What processor and OS do you use? In addition does that code really run the function calls in parallell? I think it would run it in series as it seem to wait for the result before launching the next call.

Comment: You should not call `get()` first. You call `get()` after all jobs have been run. This way you are running things in series, like skyking said.

Comment: I'm on Debian and I have an Intel Core i3-4005U 1.7 GHz, for the function calls running in parallell I have honestly no idea, I'm not familiar with the multi-processing on python so I don't know if doing it that way is the right way to do some parallell.

Comment: Yep, justhalf is right, with the get after the close and join it work like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, it's giving me some weird exception sometimes, gonna edit the post.

Comment: You are closing the pool before you finish the tasks. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no (real) difference in the two examples, as `.get()` will wait for the process to finish. So your multiprocess example will be sequential as well, but it will take more time as it spawns processes on different nodes.

First launch all your processes, and wait for the results after.

```
pool = Pool()
futures = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    for j in range(0, 3):
        futures.append(pool.apply_async(my_function,my_args))

# You can also make some additional calculation here if you want

#
# Lets see if the multiprocess stuff is finished
for i in futures:
    i.get()


pool.close()
# pool.join()
```

You can leave out the `.join()` as well, because it is not possible that the main process will finish sooner than the child processes.

Comment: Yep, you're right, but now I have some weird error that pop from time to time, see the edit of the post.

Comment: Which line is 608? As i mentioned `.join()` is useless, and it may create problems as well.

Comment: Also you are closing the pool before the tasks are finished. Dont do that.

Comment: Sorry, cropped the traceback a bit too much, the line that call the error is the line with the get().

Comment: Dont close the pool before the tasks are finished. You are trying to `get()` results from a closed pool.

Comment: So, without the join and with the pool.close() after the get the programm still crash.

Comment: Please detail `crash`, probably it is the best to open a new thread about the crash, as it probably has nothing to do with this question.